# android - RecyclerView updating every second and have a longPressListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged, long-press

I have a `RecyclerView` with a counter in every list item, as the counter callback is called, it updated the relevant fields and call `nottifyDataSetChanged`

it works fine but the problem is, I also have a long press listener attached to it, as the data is updated while user was pressing on item, the press is lost

how can I handle it?

**updater code:**

```
public void setCountDown(int countDown){
    mCountDown = countDown;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**long click listener:**

```
    holder.container.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = ((AppCompatActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
            EditAccountFragment editAccountFragmentDialog = EditAccountFragment.newInstance(_id);
            editAccountFragmentDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_account");

            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Adding Adapter on Request**

```
public class AccountAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AccountAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "ITEM_ADAPTER";

    private Cursor itemCursor;
    private Activity activity;
    private ItemColumnIds feedColumnIds;
    private int mCountDown;
    private boolean ignoreDatasetChange = false;

    /**
     * initilaizer for recycler view adapter, takes in activity although better way is to handle
     * activity related tasks within activiyt, but this is just done to speed up the overall process
     * @param activity
     */
    public AccountAdapter(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.account_item,
                parent, false);

        feedColumnIds = new ItemColumnIds();

        if (itemCursor != null){
            // initilize column indices information
            feedColumnIds.colId = itemCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    AuthContract.AccountEntry._ID);
            feedColumnIds.colAcctId = itemCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    AuthContract.AccountEntry.COLUMN_USERNAME);
            feedColumnIds.colPin = itemCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    AuthContract.AccountEntry.COLUMN_PIN);
            feedColumnIds.colIssuer = itemCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    AuthContract.AccountEntry.COLUMN_ISSUER);
        }

        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if(itemCursor == null)
            return;

        if(!itemCursor.moveToPosition(position))
            return;

        //get values from cursor
        String pin = itemCursor.getString(feedColumnIds.colPin);
        String email = itemCursor.getString(feedColumnIds.colAcctId);
        String issuer = itemCursor.getString(feedColumnIds.colIssuer);
        final long _id = itemCursor.getLong(feedColumnIds.colId);


        //set view values
        holder.tvEmail.setText(email);
        holder.tvPin.setText(pin);
        holder.tvIssuer.setText(issuer);
        holder.apCountDown.setProgress(mCountDown);

        holder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String pin = holder.tvPin.getText().toString();
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Secret Key", pin);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                Toast.makeText(activity, "OTP code "+ pin +" copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        holder.container.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = ((AppCompatActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
                EditAccountFragment editAccountFragmentDialog = EditAccountFragment.newInstance(_id);
                editAccountFragmentDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_account");

                return false;
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(itemCursor == null)
            return 0;
        return itemCursor.getCount();
    }



    /**
     * close previurous cursor if any and replace that with the new on from host class
     * @param cursor
     */
    public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        if(itemCursor != null) {
            itemCursor.close();
            itemCursor = null;
        }

        itemCursor = cursor;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void setCountDown(int countDown){
        mCountDown = countDown;

        if(!ignoreDatasetChange)
            notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * View golder for auction item entry
     */
    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvEmail;
        TextView tvPin;
        TextView tvIssuer;
//        TextView tvCountDown;
        ArcProgress apCountDown;
        View container;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvEmail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
            tvPin = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_pin);
            tvIssuer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_issuer);
            apCountDown = (ArcProgress) itemView.findViewById(R.id.arc_progress);
            container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        }
    }

    /**
     * databse column id holder for auction item
     */
    class ItemColumnIds {

        public int colId;
        public int colPin;
        public int colAcctId;
        public int colIssuer;

    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean "the press is lost"?

Comment: say I have touched down on an item expecting it to run longClickEvent, but before longClick timeout there happen a countdown update callback that updates count on all views. in this state the longclick event does not fire

Comment: your refreshing rate is less than 300ms? Why wouldn't you make it longer?

Comment: do you mind to put your adapter instead?

Comment: I have shared my adapter

Comment: the refresh rate is 1000ms but say if you start longClick sequence at say 900ms there will be no click even

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it!

So basically the issue was, every time there happens to be an update to counter the whole of adapter was populating whole of the view including the listeners as well, even setting listeners in ViewHolder did not work.

What I did, I extended my layout manager and added a method to update only the counter widget of view leaving the rest untouched.

Here is TimedGridLayoutManager:

```
public class TimedGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {

   public TimedGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
        super(context, spanCount);
    }

    //updates the counter every second
    public void setCountDown(int countDown) {
        //return null if there are no items and avoid crash
        if(this.getItemCount() <= 0)
            return;

        //get first and last visible child
        int firstPos = this.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        int lastPos = this.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

        //loop through the range and set counter
        for(int i = firstPos; i <= lastPos; i++) {
            View itemView = this.findViewByPosition(i);
            ArcProgress arcCounter = (ArcProgress) itemView.findViewById(R.id.arc_counter);
            arcCounter.setProgress(countDown);

        }
    }
}
```

It don't know if its the most efficient solution out there, but it worked like a charm for me plus I did not had to touch my adapter code at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider stopping the fast refresh while the user touches the view.

To do that, you just have to implement `onTouchEvent`, and set a flag when MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN has been detected.

```
...
if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) isUserTouching = true;
if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) isUserTouching = false;
...
```

Then, you updater code becomes :

```
public void setCountDown(int countDown){
   if (!isUserTouching) {
      mCountDown = countDown;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried the same before but problems are....ACTION_DOWN is not called if user just swipe finger away from view and I could not get a right even to capture finger leaving the view, HOVER_EXIT is also not called.
Another problem is, OnClick and OnLongClick events stop funtioning, means I am gonna have to handle them manually as well, causing into a long solution

Answer (score 0):

You must set click and long click listener on create of view holder not in bind of view holder.

update your view holder to this:

```
public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvEmail;
        TextView tvPin;
        TextView tvIssuer;
//        TextView tvCountDown;
        ArcProgress apCountDown;
        View container;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvEmail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
            tvPin = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_pin);
            tvIssuer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_issuer);
            apCountDown = (ArcProgress) itemView.findViewById(R.id.arc_progress);
            container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);

            container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String pin = tvPin.getText().toString();
                    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) itemView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Secret Key", pin);
                    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "OTP code "+ pin +" copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            container.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    FragmentManager fm = ((AppCompatActivity)itemView.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
                    EditAccountFragment editAccountFragmentDialog = EditAccountFragment.newInstance(_id);
                    editAccountFragmentDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_account");

                    return true; //if you handle it, return true!
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

and remove `holder.container.setOnClickListener` and `holder.container.setOnLongClickListener` in  `onBindViewHolder` method.